# Let $S$ be the set of self-adjoint operators on $V$ . Show $S$ is not a subspace of $L(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a complex inner product with $V \neq {\{0}\}.$

Let $S$ be the set of self-adjoint operators on $V$ . Show $S$ is not a subspace of $L(V)$

attempt: Notice that the identity operator is self adjoint, so it's in $S$.
Second, let $S,T \in L(V)$, then $(S+T)^* = S^* +T^*= S + T$ , so it's closed under addition. 
And not let $z$ be a complex scalar, then $(zT)^*= \bar z T^* = \bar z T$.

I am confuse about the scalar multiplication, can someone please  help me on this part?
Thank you.

Comment: In general, a complex number is not equal to its conjugate (so a complex multiple of a matrix does not equal the conjugate multiple of that matrix). So is this subset closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: It's not a "subspace", it is still a "subset". But otherwise yes that's right.

Comment: So it would be $(zT)^* = \bar z T^* = -zT?$

Comment: @Mahidevran: Only if $z$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: yes subspace , that what i meant

Comment: Would this be enough to show it's not closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: What you have written in your question is enough to show it is not a subspace.